# MongoDB Query - limit fields where name matches pattern

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've read everything I can find about Projection in MongoDB.  I'm hoping this is simple and I just missed it due to the overwhelming flexibility of Mongo queries.

In our MySql database, we've adopted a business practice of having "hidden" fields be prefixed with an underscore.  Our application knows how to hide these fields.

Moving some data to mongo, I need to retrieve the documents, *with ALL underscore prefixed fields omitted*.  Of course this should be done in the query rather than document manipulation after retrieval.

All the operators like $regex, $in, $all seem to apply to *values*.  I need to build a projection that ignores an unknown number of fields based on their name.  Something like:

```
db.coll.find({}, {"_*": 0})
```

Of course that doesn't work, but explains the idea.

I should note: this is necessary because the documents are editable by our application users, so I have no idea what the schema might look like.  I do know our "internal" fields are prefixed with an _, and those need to be protected by omission from the editor.

Hope it's easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate field as `hidden_fields` or something. See the following schema.

```
{_id: 'myid1', hidden_fields: {"_foo": "bar", "_foo2": "bar2"}, key1: value1 ...}
```

Now on the basis of above schema just do,

```
db.collection.find({ ... }, {hidden_fields: 1})
```

This will display hidden fields. Also you can have indexes on fields within sub documents so no loss in terms of performance as well.

Comment: All the replies were great, and helped me to understand inherent flaws in my design.  I've implemented the reverse of Sushant's suggestion - all my documents have a fixed schema at the root level, and a "content" node.  I will only present the content node to my users, therefore protecting all other parts of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality for this for good reason. It would be a nightmare to implement this kind of functionality and it would not scale nor would it be very fast.

The best way to do this currently is to set up a key-value store like:

```
{
    fields: [
        {k: "_ghhg", v: 5},
        {k: "ghg", v: 6}
    ]
}
```

You would then `$regex` on the `k` field to understand which key names (fields) have underscore in them.

As a piece of advice I would highly recommend prefixed `$regex`s since they are way more effective at using the indexes you create, i.e. for the query you show: `^_*`.

> Moving some data to mongo, I need to retrieve the documents, with ALL underscore prefixed fields omitted. Of course this should be done in the query rather than document manipulation after retrieval.

I would personally do this client side, it will be 100x faster than database side.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by @Sammaye, MongoDB doesn't support this type of query in a natural/efficient way.

However, to optimize performance if you don't always need the internal data, I'd suggest you consider creating two documents, one with the always available data, and one with just the "_internal" fields. MongoDB will read and write less, and there will be less to manipulate on the client. This would be similar to having two tables in a RDBMS (one with public and one with private data).

This could make updates to the non-internal data simple as well by just updating the entire document (if possible in your scenario).

Of course, you could then also drop the extra "_" character as well, as that just adds extra unnecessary characters to the BSON data. :)