# mongodb - Remove fields of specific patterns

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to remove fields from mongo of specific patterns. For instance, This is what my data looks like:

```
        {
        traffic_social_source_facebook: 1.0,
        traffic_social_source_instagram: 0.05,
        traffic_current_visits: 50,
        traffic_previous_visits: 100,
        traffic_source_Direct: 12
        },
        {
        traffic_social_source_twitter: 0.3,
        traffic_social_source_pinterest: 0.003,
        traffic_current_visits: 50,
        traffic_previous_visits: 100,
        traffic_source_Mail: 43
        }
```

I know how to remove single fields?, But how do I remove fields containing patterns like `traffic_social_source' or 'traffic_source'? because each row has different attribute. I need some assistance.

Comment: Why don't you create 1 field called "traffic_social" and give that field a property of "source" which has a value of facebook, twitter, instagram, etc.
Then you can just remove the traffic_social field.

Comment: I am bound to using this schema

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible then, since you can't add functions like startsWith() or something similar to the fields. I might be wrong though. Sorry for not being able to help any further!

Comment: no worries, i also tried using regular expression but it works on the value not the field names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Query - limit fields where name matches pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848959/mongodb-query-limit-fields-where-name-matches-pattern)

Comment: The solution in the link suggests to create hidden fields. I cannot modify the schema