# Exclude specific fields from all levels when querying the document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to exclude specific fields from a mongo query, I want those fields be excluded at all levels of documents

Query:

```
{
  _id: "123"
}
```

Fields:

```
{
  FieldToRemove: 0
}
```

The above query will only remove the root level record, if I add the below query

Fields:

```
{
  FieldToRemove: 0,
  embedded.FieldToRemove: 0
}
```

then It would remove the first embedded level FieldToRemove field.

Is there a way to remove FieldToRemove field from all the nested levels in a single go, I want to achieve this using normal query not aggregation if possible. If there is no way of achieving it then how can we write aggregation for it.

**Document Structure**

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "FieldToRemove":"test",
   "documentField": {
      "_id": "589",
      "FieldToRemove":"test"
    },
   "embedded":[
      {
         "_id":"456",
         "FieldToRemove":"test"
      },
      {
         "_id":"789",
         "FieldToRemove":"test",
         "embedded":[
            {
               "_id":"963",
               "FieldToRemove":"test"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "_id":"158",
         "FieldToRemove":"test"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "documentField": {
      "_id": "589"
    },
   "embedded":[
      {
         "_id":"456"
      },
      {
         "_id":"789",
         "embedded":[
            {
               "_id":"963"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "_id":"789"
      }
   ]
}
```

There are other fields in the document structure, for simplicity I just added the Field to be removed

Comment: so root level dont remove?

Comment: I want to exclude it at all levels not remove completely. When querying I don't want that field in my response at any level

Comment: yeah i meant was i the root level not exclude? in the expected result

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, I've fixed the question. I want it to be excluded at root level too. simply put I don't want that field at all in the response. Any way we can achieve this using normal mongo query?

Comment: definitely not with with a normal find. nothing comes to mind sorry

Comment: yeah no worries, even I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: [ugly](https://mongoplayground.net/p/96CVPmkdO1_) with $function

Comment: Your question is somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848959/mongodb-query-limit-fields-where-name-matches-pattern. The best possible solution without using function could be {"FieldToRemove":0, "embedded.FieldToRemove":0, "embedded.embedded.FieldToRemove":0}

Comment: @M.Navy but what if we dont know the nesting level

Comment: @M.Navy, I have currently done it the way you have mentioned but as the fields are dynamic I can get the FieldToRemove at any stage hence that solution is not optimal because I have to keep going back and editing the query to add another field in the excludes. I see only $function as a better option for now but as cmgchess mentioned its an ugly approach

Comment: @Srikar adding projection for dynamic fields using $function will impact the query performance. The ideal approach will be handling it in the client side.